# Native Query (JPA) takes long with date comparison

Tags: jpa

Has anyone got any idea how I could optimize this query so that it'll run faster? Right now it takes up to 30sec to retrieve around 3k of "containers" and thats way to long.. It's forseen that it'll have to retrieve around 1miljon records.

```
Query query = em().createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM CONTAINER where TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= TO_CHAR(:from, 'YYYY-MM-DD') " +
            "AND TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= TO_CHAR(:to, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ", Container.class);
    query.setParameter("from", from);
    query.setParameter("to", to);
    return query.getResultList();
```

JPA 2.0, Oracle DB

EDIT: I've got an index on the CREATION_DATE column:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_CONTAINER_CREATION_DATE
ON CONTAINER (CREATION_DATE);
```

it's not a named query because the TO_CHAR function doesn't seem to be supported by JPA 2.0 and I've read that it should make the query faster if there's an index..

My explain plan (still doing full table scan for some reason instead of using the index):

```
---------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name      |
---------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |           |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| CONTAINER |
---------------------------------------
```

One fix I don't like:

I've done the following..

```
TypedQuery<Container> query = em().createQuery(
"SELECT NEW Container(c.barcode, c.createdBy, c.creationDate, c.owner, c.sequence, c.containerSizeBarcode, c.a, c.b, c.c) " + 
"FROM Container c where  c.creationDate >= :from AND c.creationDate <=  :to", Container.class);
```

and I've added an absurdly long constructor to Container and this fixes the loading times.. But, this is really ugly and I don't want this tbh. Anyone any other suggestions?

Comment: is CREATION_DATE not a date data type?

Comment: @vels4j It's a TIMESTAMP

Comment: I'm stupid at times, but I fail to see how a function that converts a date into a varchar helps in doing date comparisons - or work correctly at all since you'll be comparing varchars and not timestamps. I also don't see why you can't simply select the Container instance in the JPQL query, you don't need the select NEW syntax.

Comment: @Gimby I was thinking the same things. But when I use the NEW the query takes about 1sec and when I let Hibernate create it, it takes 28 secs.. That's why I've changed it to the NEW altough I'm clueless why it takes longer for hibernate since I'm retrieving all the fields on Container..

Comment: @gregd Step 1 is to turn on hibernate query logging (google it) and see what happens. I'm suspecting that the way properties are mapped in your entities might lead to unnecessary extra queries being fired by Hibernate to populate all the fields.